# Python TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, tuples, typeerror

I'm trying to print the output of SQL output as below:

```
dwh_cur.execute("""select count (*) from sales""")
var1 = dwh_cur.fetchone()
text = 'Total Sales is ' + var1
```

var1 = 100

Expected output:

```
Total Sales is 100
```

But I get an error

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str
```

Comment: then your `var1` is a tuple. You can access the element by index. For instance var[0]. And if the element is a number, you can use `str(var[0])` as well or `text='Total Sales is %s' % var[0]`

Comment: @Aybars, thanks I got this..

Answer (score 5):

Well dwh_cur.fetchone() returns a record which is represented as a tuple of n elements,

```
dwh_cur.execute("""select count (*) from sales""")
var1 = dwh_cur.fetchone()
text = 'Total Sales is {}'.format(var1[0])
```

Might work depending on what is returned form the query.

Answer (score 2):

dwh_cur.fetchone() returns a tuple, try this:

```
dwh_cur.fetchone()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error below:

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str

When trying to concatenate **`str` type** and **`tuple` type** as shown below:

```py
    # str   # tuple 
print("a" + ("b", "c"))
```

So, I converted **`tuple` type** to **`str` type** with [**str()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) or [**join()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) as shown below:

```py
print("a" + str(("b", "c")))
print("a" + "".join(("b", "c")))
```

Then, the error above was solved:

```
a('b', 'c')
abc
```

Answer (score 0):

`var1` is not a string. You then have to convert it:

```
text = 'Total Sales is ' + str(var1)
```